# moving header in css to align correctly

Tags: css

i have this header at the top:

http://yoursdproperty.com/

how do i move the swf a little bit to the left to make it align correctly?

Comment: Sorry, move the swf to align with what exactly?

Comment: Your swf seems to align fine in Firefox 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a negative left margin? `margin-left: -10px`

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Margins](http://w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) or [Padding](http://w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) .  Playing around with these can give you a desired result.  I'd also look into the [positioning](http://w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) of your elements (in this case your header).  Setting negative padding and negative margins usually shows a layout flaw.